# How to find slow performance bottleneck in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a request which takes too long for a controller action.
I started using the rorvswild gem which gave me some insights, but it still just shows that the action is causing the problem without further details. Some callback that run before the action are also fast.

View and AR are just fine
Rails log:

```
Completed 200 OK in 504ms (Views: 218.8ms | ActiveRecord: 13.3ms)
```

rorvswild log:

```
app/controllers/app_sites_controller.rb

CODE
AppSiteDraftsController#show
375ms
x1
74%
```

In total a roundtrip time of 504ms and my views just need 218ms???
So how can I find the bottleneck?

edit:

I use RorVsWild and I noticed that respond_to is somehow the bottleneck in another action

```
RorVsWild.measure_block("Give it a name") do
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render 'dashboards/privacy/privacy'}
  end
end

 /app/controllers/dashboards_controller.rb:148
CODE
Give it a name
2800 ms
```

Even when I remove all the haml code it is still slow

**update and solved**

it turns out that my sass files are too 'heavy'. I have quite some includes. When I change assets.debug to false it renders fast
config.assets.debug = false

Comment: Can you share your code of show method ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [RorVsWild](https://www.rorvswild.com). Keep in mind, that in development environment the code is reloaded for each request. It increases volatility. To get reliable measures, I advice you to set `config.cache_classes = true` in development.rb. Then restart you server.

You have something slow in `AppSiteDraftsController#show` or in a controller callback. But it's not a slow SQL query otherwise it would have been recorded. It could be Ruby reloading your files or something else that the gem does not record.

You can deep further by measuring yourself any section of your code:

```
RorVsWild.measure_block("Give it a name") do
  # Ruby code
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexis for the hint. I used the measure block and I noticed that somehow the respond_to block is the bottle neck.Please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **chrome** as a browser, there is a plugin called **Rail panel** that analyze all AR & view requests per page and show detailed information about each request.

**Plugin:**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rails%20panel

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kVHmYzAOQQv_L2pasntd5t9BG0eDp9zrB4geIyKAP2SnfKsbqBgiGNsemGlZDUf7gjjbQ0PuWQ=w640-h400-e365]

Comment: This is basically just a visual representation of the console output. It does not give any additional insights. It's nice for visualisation but nothing more